SQLAlchemy and Alembic keeps generate the same migration when nothing changed
I have 2 migration steps, first (manual) to create schema if not exists and second to initiate 4 tables.
# Create schema DB_SCHEMA, created manually
revision: str = '7844c2c33550'
down_revision: Union[str, None] = None
branch_labels: Union[str, Sequence[str], None] = None
depends_on: Union[str, Sequence[str], None] = None


def upgrade():
    # Use op.execute to run a custom SQL command
    op.execute(f"CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS {DB_SCHEMA}")


def downgrade():
    # Reverse the custom SQL command
    op.execute(f"DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS {DB_SCHEMA}")

Second migration should create tables defined with SQLAlchemy.
# Initialize tables, migration generated with alembic autogenerate command
class Region(Base):
    __tablename__ = "regions"
    __table_args__ = {'schema': DB_SCHEMA}

    idd = Column('idd', Integer, primary_key=True)
    region_id = Column('id', Integer, unique=True)
    region = Column('region', String(20), unique=True)


class Type(Base):
    __tablename__ = "types"
    __table_args__ = {'schema': DB_SCHEMA}

    idd = Column('idd', Integer, primary_key=True)
    type_id = Column('id', Integer, unique=True)
    type = Column('type', String(5), unique=True)


class Lease(Base):
    __tablename__ = "leases"
    __table_args__ = {'schema': DB_SCHEMA}

    idd = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    id = Column('id', Integer, index=True, unique=True)
    type_id = Column('type_id', Integer, ForeignKey(f'{DB_SCHEMA}.types.id'), index=True)
    region_id = Column('region_id', Integer,  ForeignKey(f'{DB_SCHEMA}.regions.id'), index=True)


class Sale(Base):
    __tablename__ = "sales"
    __table_args__ = {'schema': DB_SCHEMA}

    idd = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    id = Column('id', Integer, index=True, unique=True)
    type_id = Column('type_id', Integer, ForeignKey(f'{DB_SCHEMA}.types.id'), index=True)
    region_id = Column('region_id', Integer,  ForeignKey(f'{DB_SCHEMA}.regions.id'), index=True)

Autogenerate show this output:
alembic revision --autogenerate -m "Init tables."
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table 'regions'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table 'types'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table 'leases'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added index ''ix_test_leases_id'' on '('id',)'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added index ''ix_test_leases_region_id'' on '('region_id',)'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added index ''ix_test_leases_type_id'' on '('type_id',)'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table 'sales'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added index ''ix_test_sales_id'' on '('id',)'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added index ''ix_test_sales_region_id'' on '('region_id',)'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added index ''ix_test_sales_type_id'' on '('type_id',)'
Generating /Users/user/projects/personal/test/test-scraper/test/migrations/versions/10cf44985d0b_init_tables.py ...  done

When I apply this changes with alembic upgrade head everything works fine:
alembic upgrade head
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 7844c2c33550 -> 10cf44985d0b, Init tables.

My problem is, when I have applied all changes already (checked in DB) and run autogenerate command again, it will shows changes that should not be there:
alembic revision --autogenerate -m "Init tables.2"
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.ddl.postgresql] Detected sequence named 'types_idd_seq' as owned by integer column 'types(idd)', assuming SERIAL and omitting
INFO  [alembic.ddl.postgresql] Detected sequence named 'sales_idd_seq' as owned by integer column 'sales(idd)', assuming SERIAL and omitting
INFO  [alembic.ddl.postgresql] Detected sequence named 'leases_idd_seq' as owned by integer column 'leases(idd)', assuming SERIAL and omitting
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected removed foreign key (region_id)(id) on table leases
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected removed foreign key (type_id)(id) on table leases
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added foreign key (region_id)(id) on table test.leases
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added foreign key (type_id)(id) on table test.leases
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected removed foreign key (type_id)(id) on table sales
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected removed foreign key (region_id)(id) on table sales
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added foreign key (region_id)(id) on table test.sales
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added foreign key (type_id)(id) on table test.sales
Generating /Users/user/projects/personal/test/test-scraper/test/migrations/versions/7f2f57f91a91_init_tables_2.py ...  done

Questions:

When I apply them and autogenerate again and again, the same output and migration is created - removed foreign key and adding foreign key. What cause this to happend and how to fix it?
Why is there always Detected sequence named information? I do not configure it.
Why is in output Generating /Users/user/projects/personal/test/... when I have no existing path like /Users/user/projects/personal/test

Posgtes version: 16.2 (docker)
Alembic version: 1.13.1
SQLAlchemy version: 2.0.29
Python version: 3.12.2
I found similar issue here: Alembic drops and creates foreign key constraints (autogenerate) when the table has different schema than the referenced columns but there is no answer for 1 year and 5 months.
